# bad sockid occured when receive can frame

Tags: c, linux, sockets, can-bus

I have developed a server under Linux, it can listen send/receive isotp frame (can).

The server works fine, but I remarked when I run dmesg I get :

```
[   83.368708] Bad sockid 1 instead of 2 (000b0001)
[   83.457905] Bad sockid 1 instead of 2 (000b0001)
[   83.645633] Bad sockid 1 instead of 2 (000b0001)
[   83.816618] Bad sockid 1 instead of 2 (000b0001)
[   83.987874] Bad sockid 1 instead of 2 (000b0001)
[   84.138589] Bad sockid 1 instead of 2 (000b0001)
[   84.389584] Bad sockid 1 instead of 2 (000b0001)
[   84.543561] Bad sockid 1 instead of 2 (000b0001)
[   84.833585] Bad sockid 1 instead of 2 (000b0001)
[   85.145563] Bad sockid 1 instead of 2 (000b0001)
[   85.517794] Bad sockid 1 instead of 2 (000b0001)
[   85.708565] Bad sockid 1 instead of 2 (000b0001)
[   85.880558] Bad sockid 1 instead of 2 (000b0001)
[   86.031514] Bad sockid 1 instead of 2 (000b0001)
[   86.222621] Bad sockid 1 instead of 2 (000b0001)
[   86.332651] Bad sockid 1 instead of 2 (000b0001)
[   86.464498] Bad sockid 1 instead of 2 (000b0001)
[   86.621709] Bad sockid 1 instead of 2 (000b0001)
[   86.797741] Bad sockid 1 instead of 2 (000b0001)
[   87.148488] Bad sockid 1 instead of 2 (000b0001)
[   87.300492] Bad sockid 1 instead of 2 (000b0001)
[   87.471440] Bad sockid 1 instead of 2 (000b0001)
```

each time when receive frame from remote node

```
#define SOCKET_ID 9

...

s = socket(PF_CAN,SOCK_DGRAM,SOCKET_ID);
if(s < 0)
{
      perror("error when create the socket");
      goto error;
}else
{
    //some treatment
}
...
error:
...
```

What is the root cause of this error and how to fix it?